# Convert date to xml web service date asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, date

I'm working on asp.net c# project, where I'm taking input from user as DD/MM/YYYY.

So I want to pass the input date by the user to the web service that expects date format as ( 2017-07-15T08:01:55.800Z ) of format < type="impl:DateBean" />

Now i'm having problem converting the input to YYYY-DD-MMT

your help and reference to any useful topic is appreacited

What ever value I'm trying I'm getting error "can't implicitly convert type "[string], [system.datetime] or whatsover. to type 'mywebservice.DateBean

This is how I'm constructing to call the web service:

```
MyWebService.top_ELEMENT_NAME srvBeanIn = new MyWebService.top_ELEMENT_NAME();
srvBeanIn.input = new MyWebService.webServiceElementTop();
srvBeanIn.input.paymentOrder = new MyWebService.ELEMENT_NAME[1];
srvBeanIn.input.paymentOrder[0] = new MyWebService.ELEMENT_NAME();
```

This is how i'm trying to pass the date

```
var input = "17/07/2017";
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
const string inputFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
DateTime parsed;


try
{
  parsed = DateTime.ParseExact(input, inputFormat, provider);
  Debug.WriteLine("parsed nj wire= " + parsed);
  var isoResult = parsed.ToUniversalTime().ToString("o"); //--> 2017-07-15T08:01:55.800Z
  srvBeanIn.input.paymentOrder[0].MyDate.date = parsed;

}
catch (FormatException)
{
  Debug.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", input);
}
```

And here's the xml tag I have in the WSDL

```
 <xsd:complexType name="DateBean">
        <xsd:complexContent mixed="false">
          <xsd:extension base="impl:BaseSOIBean">
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="date" nillable="true" type="xsd:dateTime" />
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
      </xsd:complexType>


<xsd:element name="swiftDate" nillable="true" type="impl:DateBean" />
```

Comment: is it DataContractSerializer you using on webservice? You need to provide the code here as more information.

Comment: I don't have source code but i have the wsdl of the web service and here's the element: <xsd:element name="Date" nillable="true" type="impl:DateBean" />

Comment: How you constructing request..  that code is important beforehand.

Comment: Please check the update, thank you

Answer (score 0):

First parse the string input to a `DateTime` using the specified input format, then convert to UTC, then convert to ISO string `isoResult`:

```
var input = "17/07/2017";

CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

const string inputFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
DateTime parsed;

try {
    parsed = DateTime.ParseExact(input, inputFormat, provider);
    var isoResult = parsed.ToUniversalTime().ToString("o");
}   
catch (FormatException) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", input);
}
```

Use the ISO string to create the DateBean.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. 
I still get the same error as passing var or string is not acceptable with tihs error <cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'MyWebService.DateBean'

Comment: I am not familiar with the `DateBean` type. Is it a custom type of your WebService? Try to instantiate a new DateBean object using the converted string or DateTime, then add it to the request.

Comment: can I convert parsed.ToUniversalTime().ToString("o")  to date? because [var] or [string] is not accepted.

Comment: `parsed.ToUniversalTime()` is a `DateTime` in UTC. If DateBean does not accept a string, there is not need to convert this DateTime to ISO format (value will be the same for different string formats).